# ~ character in master page URL

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, character

I am developing an `ASP.NET` application using a `masterpage`.

As default the `master page` is referred on top of all the pages as

```
masterpagefile="~/mymasterpage.Master".
```

My application works perfectly in the test environments under `IIS 6.0` or `7.0`

When I publish it to the server (under `IIS 6.0` - for which I don't know the server configuration) it gives me an error for the master page URL.

When I remove the "~/" from all the pages it works perfectly but I would like to know the reason and also how can I change the configuration to make it work even with the following URL : `"~/mymasterpage.Master"`

Thanks

Comment: What is the target .net framework for the web application, on the server where it is published? Compare this with your test environment.

Comment: Follow this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem; actually "~/" refers to application root and my application was inside a virtual directory instead of an application. I just converted the virtual directory to an application and it's working fine !